# Get absolute URL of jfx path

Tags: java, path, resources, javafx, loading

This line

```
URL contexturl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("ClassLoader/Test/someFile.xml");
```

gives me the following `contexturl.toString()` string for the resource file `someFile.xml`:

```
jfx://ClassLoader/Test/someFile.xml
```

What does this mean and how can I obtain the absolute file system path of the resource?

The problem is also that `contexturl.getPath()` returns `null`.

The `someFile.xml` file is packaged in some jar file can be loaded as expected. However, I also want to load another file which is in the same folder of the jar but not packaged in the jar, so its external and therefore I need the file system path.

Any hints how to retrieve this path?

Comment: your "ClassLoader" folder is at the root of the JAR ? To retrieve the  path  ---->  System.getProperty("user.dir")

Comment: user.dir returns C:\windows\system32, so this is not an option to get the path.

Comment: no shit, how so? In my case it returns the folder where JAR is located (Windows 7)